# Assigning an anonymous function to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm running this javasrcipt code on google chrome browser as an html script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bar=function() {
        var name='tanzeel';
        console.log('inside a function');
    }
    console.log('My name is ' +bar.name);
</script>
```

I'm coming from java and cpp background. My knowledge about oop says that function in js are instantiated as an object and here variable `bar` is pointing to that object. So I can access all the properties of that object. Then why `console.log('My name is ' +bar.name)` is printing `My name is bar` instead of the string `My name is tanzeel`.
Please correct me where i am wrong and what else do i need to know. Thanks.

Comment: `bar.name` is accessing the name of the function. If you want a constructor, you need to use `new bar()` as well as assigning `this.name`, since `var name` is a function-scoped variable.

Comment: Because functions have names: [`Function.prototype.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

Comment: In ES6 you can use `class` keyword very similar to java classes. And try to avoid `var` instead use `let` or `const`

Comment: *"Please correct me where i am wrong"* you're mixing/confusing object properties with local variables. The only quirk here is that, in JS, functions have properties and methods too. like `name` like `length` *(the number of arguments defined)* `call()` and `bind()`, ... And that you can store functions/methods in variables and pass them around like any other value.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable may be "pointing" (dat cpp lingo ;)) to an object, but you can't just treat that object any how you want. The object is a function in this case, so you cannot treat the function's body as having fields in the sense of a regular class.

The output you get is the name of the function.

---

To have this work, you must instantiate the object using `new` keyword. You also have to assign properties to the class in order to access them.

```
var bar=function() {
    this.name='tanzeel';
    //console.log('inside a function');
}
var b = new bar()
console.log(b.name);
```

Comment: Oh. Which in my case is `bar`. Now I got it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate issues here.

First, functions are objects and can have properties. Variables defined in the scope of a function are *completely* different to properties of the function object. They exist only while the function is running (although c.f. closures) and are referred to *directly* and not in relation to the function.

Second, functions can have names. Typically this comes from an explicit name in the function expression:

```
var bar = function foo () { };
```

… but since a change in JS a few years ago, *anonymous* function expressions get a name from the variable that they are assigned to.

```
var bar = function () { };
```

The fact that you have a variable named `name` inside the function is unrelated to the function having a property called `name`.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign string `tanzeel` to variable `name`, you don't change `name` property of the bar function. Instead you just create `name` variable in the lexical environment of `bar` function.

`bar.name` in `console.log` statement evaluates to `bar` because the function infers [it from it's syntactic position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Inferred_function_names)

Answer (score 1):

The expected behaviour is understandable. This is because functions are treated as objects in javascript. Each object has a set of properties. Similarly, functions have a property **`name`** in their prototype chain which evaluates to the name of the function. Read more here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name
Also, check out the console in the image below. You can see a name property there inside the constructor.

[image]